# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TEXT_ENCODING') When Loading Blazor Page Via Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor

When I go directly to a link in a Browser window for one page in my Serverside .Net 6.0 application it shows the following in Developer Tools and Blazor code doesn't execute for control event handlers

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TEXT_ENCODING')

Other pages that work in a similar manner do not give this error.  I have copied the page to a different name / route but the error remains.

What could be causing the issue on this one particular page?

Comment: I see `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'runtime')` but I have no idea why.